# InvalidCastException when using Entity Framework

Tags: c#, http, entity-framework-5, asp.net-web-api2

I am trying to save a List of Users in a Conversation class but I am getting an `InvalidCastException` when performing a POST.

This is my User class:

```
public class User
{
    [Key]
    [DataMember]
    public String Email { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public String Password { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public Boolean Admin { get; set; }

    public User(String email, String password, Boolean admin)
    {
        Email = email;
        Password = password;
        Admin = admin;
    }
}
```

And this is my Conversation class:

```
[DataContract]
public class Conversation
{
    [Key]
    [DataMember]
    public string Key { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string ConversationName { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string Administrator { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    [ForeignKey("Email")]
    public List<User> Members { get; set; }

    public Conversation(string key, string name, string admin, List<User> members)
    {
        Key = key;
        ConversationName = name;
        Administrator = admin;
        Members = members;
    }

    public Conversation()
    {

    }
}
```

This is the Conversation controller:

POST:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> PostConversation(Conversation convo)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }

        foreach (var user in convo.Members)
        {
            db.Entry(user).State = EntityState.Unchanged;
        }

        db.Conversations.Add(convo);
        await db.SaveChangesAsync();

        return CreatedAtRoute("DefaultApi", new { name = convo.Key }, convo);
    }
```

GET:

```
[HttpGet]
public IQueryable<Conversation> GetConversations()
{
    return db.Conversations;
}
```

**EDIT**
Post statement:

```
{
"Key": "123",
"ConversationName": "Test",
"Administrator": "Ken",
"Members": [{"Email": "y@12.com","Password" : "Passw-1", "Admin" : "true"},
            {"Email": "y@123.com","Password" : "Passw-1", "Admin" : "false"}]
}
```

The error I am getting is:

> "ExceptionMessage": "Unable to cast object of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[AcademicAssistant.Models.User]' to type 'AcademicAssistant.Models.User'.",

Comment: Why are you calling `db.Conversations.Add` twice? Also, do you have any more information about where the error occurs, or if it gives you any details regarding which property is incorrect.

Comment: You have 3 required parameters on your user constructor (email, password, and admin). Unless you are passing the email, password, and admin on each member in the conversation, it will not be able to construct your user objects on each member. Since I can't see what you are actually posting, I can't be sure, but I doubt you are posting passwords for the users in the conversation.

Comment: @Steve thank you for pointing that out, that was a mistake! It is the "Members" property that is giving the trouble. I have edited the question to include more information!

Comment: @randyh22 should have included that originally.. my bad! It is included now though. I am passing a User into the Conversation and so I am passing the password along with the Email and Admin. It will not be used further in the code but I must include it to be able to use the User class.

Comment: @semiColon I am wondering if it is having trouble converting your admin properties, which are strings ("true" and "false") to boolean as defined in your user class.

Comment: 1)Why do you have this "ForeignKey("Email")" in conversation? 2) User class doesn't have constructor without args ? 3) which line of code is throwing the exception?

Comment: @randyh22 I don't think this is the problem, as in the User class "Admin" refers to whether of not this person has admin access whereas in the Conversation class "Administrator" refers to who is the administrator of a group. I don't think these fields are related in theory or code, unless it is making a link that I am unaware of?

Comment: When you post the data, .net is going to map it to your convo variable which is a Conversation. It is also going to automatically map the members in the convo to the user class. Your error message is telling you it cannot map what you are passing in to the user class.

Comment: @tede24 1) I have the ForeignKey there as it is referencing the property in the User class that will be used to connect the two. Is this wrong?   2) I have tried it with a constructor with no args but there is still no change. 3) Is it not giving me a specific line. Just the shown exception in Postman!

Comment: @randyh22 I am aware of this, however I do not know what is causing the problem as it seems like everything matches.. I am obviously missing something but I don't know what!

Comment: i tried with your sample JSON and the exact DataContract and was able to get the controller action parameter (Convo) populated properly with all the members.. can you try in a non-POSTMAN way? i used the chrome rest client.

Comment: @RajaNadar Still isn't working for me! Is it because of my database that it is not working?

Comment: @semicolon 1) it's at least strange.. your relation is N:N right? or 1:N? in any case the FK is in conversation so that attribute seems wrong. 3) it's so open to guess if we can't know where is the exception raised, basically I would like to know if it's about model binding or inside the method, can you set a breakpoint at the beginning of method and see if it's hit?

Comment: @semiColon put a breakpoint in your method and let us know where the error occurs.. does it even hit the breakpoint?

Comment: @tede24 I have inserted break points and it is crashing when it gets to `db.Conversations.Add(convo);`. Everything is fine until this line

Comment: @RajaNadar `db.Conversations.Add(convo);` this is the trouble maker

Comment: could you clarify is it's N:N or 1:N? I think your problem is in entities configurations

Comment: @tede24 my apologies, it is a N:N relationship

Comment: so remove that ForeingKey attribute from Conversation, and add a public ICollection<Conversation> Conversations in user, to let EF that it's N:N

Comment: @tede24 I have done this and now get this exception `"ExceptionMessage": "The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint \"FK_dbo.UserConversations_dbo.Users_User_Email\". The conflict occurred in database \"AA_db\", table \"dbo.Users\", column 'Email'`

Comment: So you are mucho more close now!! It was a bad entities configuration which was producing the error. Now, have you checked users email fields have value?

Comment: @tede24 I am using the same piece of JSON that I have in the question above. Should I be including the new Conversations property anywhere?

Comment: No I mean checking if your convo object is ok and their users also. Note that add is not complaining anymore now the exception is on SaveChanges

Comment: @tede24 It seems to be fine! The object is getting created and the Users are entering the Members list in the Conversation class but yet it is still crashing

Comment: My friend, all this question was too broad.. The point now is EF complaints when tries to insert data in the table that implements the n:n relationship (you don't have an entity but EF implements a table for the relation) and seems it fails the fk between that table and user table. So my suggestion is to debug, stop before SaveChanges and be sure all entities are right and have their pks. Also I would use sql profiler to see the sql command and try to discover what else you have wrong, as model setting is right now

Comment: Thank you for your help getting me this far @tede24! It is appreciated. I will debug further until I find the problem

Comment: Glad to help. I will add an answer about the model error to help other people

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your model is wrong. As you have a N:N relationship between `Conversation` and `User` you need to remove `ForeingKey` attribute from conversation before `Members`, and you need to add `ICollection<Conversation> Conversation` property in User class, or go further and configure the relationship as you need with FluentApi